# Table design problem

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm looking for a SQL design solution for the following problem. The idea is that I have a validation form that contains the client's data. Each client can log in to his account and edit his data. After that I have to save it to the database. After validation of the content of the data, I have to update the original fields.

Actually each client has a photovoltaic installation. Each installation contains one or more inverters and at each one there is N solar panels that are attached. All of the inverters are attached to an electrical meter.

I choose to save only the difference between the data stored in the db and the modified data. e.g: if the client changes only the brand of his inverter I will not save all the data, but only the modified inverter brand. I then have to validate the brand and to update it in the table `Inverters`.

My first idea to solve that issue is to work with 2 tables: `validation_data` and `validation_fields`. The table `validation_fields` contains all the fields that can be updated (`vaf_field`). The table `validation_data` is a temporary table. It contains the id of the field to update (`vad_vaf_id`, who is also the foreign key to the table `validation_fields`) and the value (`vad_value`). `vad_met_id` is the foreign key to link to the meter. Nothing special :) Once the data is verified, `vad_is_treated` will have the value `1`. The default is `0`.

```
+-----------------+   +-------------------+
| validation_data |   | validation_fields |
+-----------------+   +-------------------+
| vad_id          |   | vaf_id            |
| vad_met_id      |   | vaf_field         |
| vad_vaf_id      |   +-------------------+
| vad_value       |
| vad_is_treated  |
+-----------------+
```

So that logic is good, or at least it works fine for me, but only if the client possesses only one inverter. As I said I save only the difference between the existing and modified data. So if the client changes the brand of two of his inverters, in the `validation_data` table I will have:

```
+--------+------------+------------+--------------+
| vad_id | vad_met_id | vad_vaf_id |   vad_value  |
+--------+------------+----------- +--------------+
|      1 |     1234   |          2 |        Peter |
|      2 |     1234   |          3 |    SMA 1400S |
|      3 |     1234   |          3 |    SMA 1400S |
+--------+------------+------------+--------------+
```

Consider that if `vad_vaf_id` is `2`, that is the `firstname` field, and `3` - the inverter's brand.

So okay, for the first line all is good, the client changed his firstname. But for the second and the third line there is a problem. The client changed the brand of his inverters but for which one? The first and the second inverter, or the first and the third, or the second and the third?

Do you have any idea how I can deal with that?

Answer (score 1):

If your `vad_vaf_id` does not sufficiently designate the target value, perhaps you should add a new column in your temporary table to provide that information? Something like `vad_target`?

```
+-----------------+   +-------------------+
| validation_data |   | validation_fields |
+-----------------+   +-------------------+
| vad_id          |   | vaf_id            |
| vad_met_id      |   | vaf_field         |
| vad_vaf_id      |   +-------------------+
| vad_target      |
| vad_value       |
| vad_is_treated  |
+-----------------+
```

When user changes his firstname, leave the field `NULL`. When there are multiple possible targets (i.e. with inverters), use inverter's id.